# Reduce and object deconstruction/assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's assume I have two simple objects and I want to create a third one that will be joining their properties. This works perfectly:

```js
(()=>{
  const a1 = {a: 2, b: 3}
  const b1 = {a: 100, c: 5}
  return {...a1, ...b1}
})()
// { a: 100, b: 3, c: 5 }
```

But it stops working once I try to create a new object derived from b1 using `.reduce`. For a sake of simplicity let's create a reduce function that simply makes a shallow copy of the b1 object:

```js
let r = (()=>{
  const a1 = {a: 2, b: 3}
  const b1 = {a: 100, c: 5},
  b2 = Object.entries(b1).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {value}), {})
  console.log(b2) // {a: 100 c: 5}
  return {...a1, ...b2}
})()
console.log(r);// { a: 2, b: 3 }
```

I have a feeling that there is something about `.reduce` function that I just don't understand. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: When the snippet runs, `b2` is `{}`, an empty object.

Comment: @Pointy if you use `console.log(b2.a)` it prints 100

Comment: @MichałSadowski because its not enumerable, so it won't show when logging the object. `Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {value: value, enumerable: true})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark the property as enumerable

```
Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {value, enumerable: true});
```

Why not just using the function `Object.assign` instead, it's straightforward.

```js
let r = (()=> {
  const a1 = {a: 2, b: 3};
  const b1 = {a: 100, c: 5};
  const b2 = Object.entries(b1).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => Object.assign(acc, {[key]: value}), {})
  console.log(b2); // {a: 100 c: 5}
  return {...a1, ...b2}
})()
console.log(r); // { a: 2, b: 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, properties created with `defineProperty` are not enumerable, so they won't be included with a spread.

To fix:

```
b2 = Object.entries(b1).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
  Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {value, enumerable: true})
, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

One fix could be to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a copy of `b1` like:

```js
let r = (()=>{
  const a1 = {a: 2, b: 3}
  const b1 = {a: 100, c: 5}
  const b2 = Object.assign({}, b1)
  console.log(b2) // {a: 100 c: 5}
  return {...a1, ...b2}
})()

console.log(r); // { a: 100, b: 3, c: 5 }
```